# Livewire Content Too Large large file not uploading

Tags: laravel-livewire

I am New To Livewire,

I want to upload Image > 15 MB size .

I have gone through the document of livewire.

They Said,

You can change the upload file size

```
'temporary_file_upload' => [
        'disk' => null,        // Example: 'local', 's3'              Default: 'default'
        '
```

> rules' => ['required', 'file', 'max:1024000'],

```
   // Example: ['file', 'mimes:png,jpg']  Default: ['required', 'file', 'max:12288'] (12MB)
        'directory' => null,   // Example: 'tmp'                      Default  'livewire-tmp'
        'middleware' => null,  // Example: 'throttle:5,1'             Default: 'throttle:60,1'
        'preview_mimes' => [   // Supported file types for temporary pre-signed file URLs.
            'png', 'gif', 'bmp', 'svg', 'wav', 'mp4',
            'mov', 'avi', 'wmv', 'mp3', 'm4a',
            'jpg', 'jpeg', 'mpga', 'webp', 'wma',
        ],
        'max_upload_time' => 60, // Max duration (in minutes) before an upload gets invalidated.
    ],
```

But Still Not Upload the large file.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: In My php.ini

post_max_size=500M
upload_max_filesize=400M

Comment: @OzanKurt Content Too Large.

Comment: maybe after the change in rules try restarting the server and clearing cache. might help i am not sure but.

Comment: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/file-uploads#global-validation

Comment: @WhoDoYouthinkami

Yes I Have done the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Changes in conf/livewire.php aren't enough. It necessary to change php.ini.  In php.ini find and set:
post_max_size = 16M
upload_max_filesize = 16M
and then restart fpm service or restart your computer. It helps me.

p.s. If you don't know where php.ini is, create a route foe example

```
Route::get('/test/page', function (){
    dd(phpinfo());
});
```

and looking for "Configuration File (php.ini) Path"